# Steam on Wine no text

Tags: wine, steam

When I launch Steam through Wine, no text is shown, just buttons. I am running Wine version 1.6. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it there a reason to use Steam through Wine? Steam has it's own Linux native software and it can both installed via terminal or the software center. See this: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/steam-launcher/

Comment: Well the steam Linux client is insanely buggy and constantly crashes. Plus not all games have been properly or at all ported to linux

Comment: I see, but now that you face no text on Wine, it sounds "buggy" the same as the Linux client. Have you considered using a Virtual Machine? You may have a better experience but I admit it's hungry on resources consumption and you'll find some troubles for hardware acceleration.

Comment: I've tried virtual machine, horrible mouse problems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a terminal and enter the command:

```
wine reg add 'HKCU\Software\Valve\Steam' /v DWriteEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000
```

This will disable DWrite for only Steam.  Alternatively, you can run the following:

```
wine /path/to/Steam.exe -no-dwrite
```